# Automatic assembly of multiple Kinect 2 grayscale depth images to a depth map

Tags: matlab, kinect, depth

The project is about measurement of different objects under the Kinect 2. The image acquisition code sample from the SDK is adapted in a way to save the depth information at the whole range and without limiting the values at 0-255.
The Kinect is mounted on a beam hoist and moved in a straight line over the model. At every stop, multiple images are taken, the mean calculated and the error correction applied. Afterwards the images are put together to have a big depth map instead of multiple depth images.

Due to the reduced image size (to limit the influence of the noisy edges), every image has a size of 350x300 pixels. For the moment, the test is done with three images to be put together. As with the final program, I know in which direction the images are taken. Due to the beam hoist, there is no rotation, only translation.

In Matlab the images are saved as matrices with the depth values going from 0 to 8000. As I could only find ideas on how to treat images, the depth maps are transformed into images with a colorbar. Then only the color part is saved and put into the stitching script, i.e. not the axes and the grey part around the image.

The stitching algorithm doesn’t work. It seems to me that the grayscale-images don’t have enough contrast to be treated by the algorithms. Maybe I am just searching in the wrong direction?

Any ideas on how to treat this challenge?

Comment: The typical way to do such a thing is convert the kinect data to a 3d pointCloud / mesh. Multiple point clouds can be stitched together using Iterative Closest Point (ICP) algorithm like the once which can be found in the point cloud library (PCL).  If you would know the translation of the beam accurately enough (distance, parallelism to object/coordinate system), you should be able to skip the ICP and just to a pointCloud transform / translation. This will be far more robust than using the ICP algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for PCL, didn't know that project yet.